# Android4.4 or later, how to synchronize system data?

Tags: android, root

If not using root in android 4.4 or after,  how to record the screen and synchronize it to computers? Can anyone provide an idea or an open-source software? The old method  that using root to gain access to system data is no longer working after android 4.4..  Thanks a lot.

Comment: _"The old method that using root to gain access to system data is no longer working after android 4.4"_ - Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

> If not using root in android 4.4 or after, how to record the screen and synchronize it to computers?

Fortunately, this is not possible, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons. SDK apps cannot read the screen, except perhaps on rooted devices.